# What's the difference between "ein-" after article as adjective and as a replacement for article as a word for "one" (a counter)

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, adjective

Reading through *Hammer*, I've come across the use of *einer* as determinative. One example the book gives is:

> Der eine deutsche Tourist beschwerte sich.

How does this differ from

> Ein deutscher Tourist beschwerte sich.

Both appear to mean the same thing, "One German tourist complained."

Comment: Using `code` highlights for quotations is not exactly recommended.

Comment: *That one German tourist complained* vs. *A German tourist complained*. In other words: *der eine Tourist* means *that one (single) tourist*, not just *one tourist*.

Answer (score 6):

> Ein deutscher Tourist beschwerte sich.

This simply means that there was a German tourist who complained.

> Der eine deutsche Tourist beschwerte sich.

This implies that there was more than one German tourist (most likely two), and one of them complained.

So the first sentence translates to: *A German tourist complained*. The second translates to something like *One German tourist complained [and the other(s) didn't]*

Another possibility is that there was only one German tourist and that this tourist complained. Without context it is impossible to tell which meaning is the intended one.

Comment: Yes, one could also interpret *eine* that way,  similar to *the one with the beard*. I guess, some context is missing to choose the correct translation, *Hammer* is not really providing it.

Comment: The second sentence could also mean that there are many tourists from different origins, but the (only) German one complained.

Answer (score 1):

The correct translation is:

> The single German tourist complained.

There were no other German tourists available, which were satisfied. While your translation is not wrong, it loses considerable information.

Comment: Is there a _not_ missing before _satisfied_? Otherwise I don't get that sentence.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: this is also a valid sentence. We agree the all German tourists (which in fact was only one) complained. Would additional ones also have complained? If assuming so, inserting another *not* is justified. If not, the present sentence is fine.

Comment: @guidot: The sub-sentence "which were satisfied" misses a *not*, no matter how you explain it. You could just as well omit it: "There were no other German tourists present." FWIW, *available* means *verfügbar*. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That does not seem quite right; it would have to be _der einzige deutsche Tourist_, or _der alleinige deutsche Tourist_.  The meaning of _der eine deutsche Tourist_ is more like "one of the (two or more) German tourists"

Comment: @guidot Vielleicht ist es auch mein schlechtes Englisch. Ich verstehe Deinen Text so: _Der eine deutsche Tourist beschwerte sich. Es gab keine anderen deutschen Touristen, die zufrieden waren._ Und das klingt für mich widersprüchlich. Ich hätte erwartet: _Es gab keine anderen deutschen Touristen, die **unzufrieden** waren._

Comment: @OliverMason: You are right if you consider RHa's translation as correct, but this is not the only interpretation possible.

Answer (score 0):

Even though "der eine deutsche Tourist" can mean that there is only one, I disagree with the conclusion that this is the only correct interpretation. In German the expression "some people do this, others do that" is often used with singular, so it could also mean "der eine deutsche Tourist beschwert sich, der andere nimmt die Zustände klaglos hin".

Comment: English: *One tourist complains, another takes it without any complaints*. Only in combinations, AFAIK, i.e. *der/die/das eine ... der/die/das andere*.

Comment: As this answer does not answer the question, it should rather be a comment.